# Simple RESTful api code in Eclipse giving HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

I'm starting to learn REST API with eclipse and I encountered HTTP Status 500- Internal Server Error. I tried using tomcat 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, same error in all servers.
Please help me out. (output works for normal MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)s

Here's the code I wrote-

Alien.java:

```
package com.amishraj.demorest1;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {

    private String name;
    private int points;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
```

AlienResources.Java:

```
package com.amishraj.demorest1;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResources
{
    /*@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String helloworld() {
        return "HELOL WORLD";

    } */

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Alien getAlien() {

        System.out.println("getAlien called");

        Alien a1= new Alien();
        a1.setPoints(100);
        a1.setName("Amish");
        return a1;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Welcome ! can we have more details please ? stacktrace ?

Comment: Javadoc ? What I've missed?

Comment: The attached Javadoc could not be retrieved as the specified Javadoc location is either wrong or currently not accessible.

I got this message when hovering my cursor over

 ```import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
```

I dont know how to give stacktrace

Comment: Even though I'm pretty I have javadoc

Comment: Add stacktrace in your question

Comment: How do I do that? Also I'm not getting any exceptions in the console

Comment: the full message I get in the internal server error is-

Type Status Report

Message Internal Server Error

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Don't you have to declare it's a JAX-RS application with a javax.ws.rs.core.Application subclass with a @ApplicationPath annotation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try something like this.

 @XmlElement
 private String name;

 @XmlElement
 private int points;
 
and Remove @XmlElement from,

public void setName(String name)

public void setPoints(int points)